# SemanticUi: fill search input in Menu Header

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I havings problems trying to fill this search input to entire width menu, but SemanticUI uses flexbox for menu items.

```
    <div class="ui top attached teal inverted large menu">
    <div class="header item">Header</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="ui search item">
            <div class="ui left icon large input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search input">
            <i class="search link icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="results"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right menu">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="ui primary button">Button1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="ui red button">
                Button2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoGNvP

I can think only do it with javascript? or there is a way to solve with css only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and research, this is the shortest solution I found

```
.ui.menu .search {
  flex: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOQXjL